# Using jQuery to change background color on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery and I have read through threads on this topic, but I am having some trouble understanding the logic and after re-writing my code, I'm still unable to get it to work.

I have two buttons and I would like for each one to change the background color and text color on click. Here is a link to my **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/allisoncodes/zdpbx518/)**

Any feedback or advice would be very appreciated. Thanks!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#footer").on("click", "#purple', function() {
       $(this).css("background-color", "#9683ec");
       $(this).css("color", "#2d2746");
    });

    $("footer").on("click", "#blue', function() {
       $(this).css("background-color", "#00bfff");
       $(this).css("color", "#002633");
    });
});
```

Comment: You're not referencing jQuery in your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Can you tell me more?

Comment: are you sure that you have linked jquery correctly

Comment: add this to your project

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: All your code is right. You just have to to correct your quotes in your code.  At #purple and #blue you open double quotes and close single quotes. Make sure you have to use either single quotes or double quotes. But not one single quote and one double quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/zdpbx518/17/)**

The `click` event is looking for a descendant with an `id` of `#purple` or `#blue` and there isn't one in both cases.

From the jQuery documentation for the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) function:

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.

Wrapping the text within the buttons with a `span` and setting the `id` value on the spans instead will work.

Also, it looks like you're not targeting the `body` on the click event, so the `background-color` will not change as intended.

**HTML**

```
<footer>
  <button><span id="purple">Purple</span></button>
  <button><span id="blue">Blue</span></button>
  <p>&copy;Allison Harris 2016</p>
</footer>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").on("click", "#purple", function() {
    $('body').css("background-color", "#9683ec");
  });

  $("button").on("click", "#blue", function() {
    $('body').css("background-color", "#00bfff");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to get my code to work. Here is an updated link: https://jsfiddle.net/allisoncodes/zdpbx518/18/

Comment: @AllisonH. You're welcome. The code in your fiddle changes the color of the button and not the background.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can do it.try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>hover</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
      }

   div.myclass{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
   }
  
  #mybotton{
    background-color: orange;
    color: black;
  }

    </style>

    </head>
    <body>

     <div class="myclass"></div>
     <br/>
     <button id="mybotton">my button</button>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myclass").click(function(){
      $(this).css({"background-color":"red"});
    });

    $("#mybotton").click(function(){
      $(this).css({"color":"white", "background-color":"red"});
    });

   });
   </script>

    </body>




    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in `"#purple'` and `"#blue'` using single qoute and double quotes in the same string, you should choose one of them :

```
$("#footer").on("click", "#purple", function() {
//OR
$("#footer").on("click", '#purple', function() {
```

Also you could attach multiple css in same time using :

```
$(this).css({ "background-color": "#9683ec", "color": "#2d2746" })
```

Instead of :

```
$(this).css("background-color", "#9683ec");
$(this).css("color", "#2d2746");
```

Finally you miss id selector sign `#` in :

```
$("footer").on("click", "#blue", function() {
__^
```

Full code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#footer").on("click", "#purple", function() {
         $(this).css({ "background-color": "#9683ec", "color": "#2d2746" })
    });

    $("#footer").on("click", "#blue", function() {
         $(this).css({ "background-color": "#00bfff", "color": "#002633" })
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The `#footer` in should be a normal `footer`, I think.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Of course, but since the HTML footer doesn't have an ID and you corrected it as if it was, I wanted to clarify it

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("#purple").click(function() {
       $(this).css("background-color", "#9683ec");
   });
   $("#blue").click(function() {
       $(this).css("background-color", "#00bfff");
   });
});
```

```css
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #091232;
 background-color: #00ced1;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  border-radius: 20%;
 background-color: #ffff33;
  font-color: #000000;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>#bothcats</title>

<body>
  <h1>Toph and Oscar</h1>
  <div id="container">
    <h2>#bothcats</h2>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/rEn4Ze8.png" style="max-width:80%">
    <p>Toph and Oscar are the ultimate duo.</p>
    <h2>You decide</h2>
    <p>Would you like to see them on blue or purple? Make your choice below.</p>
  </div>

</body>
<footer>
  <button id="purple">Purple</button>
  <button id="blue">Blue</button>
  <p>&copy;Allison Harris 2016</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful! I'm now realizing that maybe I shouldn't be using "this" because I actually want to change the background color and text color  of the **entire page** upon click. Could you help me with the logic of this?

Comment: In that case you can use $("body") instead of $(this).

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <style>
        body
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
        div
        {
            margin: auto;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #ccc;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="myclass"></div>
        <br />
        <button id="purple">Purple</button>
        <button id="blue">Blue</button>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#purple").on('click', function()
                {
                    $('div').css("background-color", "purple");
                });
                $("#blue").on('click', function()
                {
                    $('div').css("background-color", "blue");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```